# rails loop doesn't create the first form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a loop which iterates through an array of objects creating a form for each.

```
%h4
- @build.tables.where(build: @build, style: "raw").each do |table|
      = form_for :table, :url => table_global_timestamp_path(table), :method => :post, :html => { :class => ""}, authenticity_token: true, remote: true do |f|
        .row.puffer
          .col-lg-12
            = f.label :global_timestamp, "Choose Timestamp for #{table.collection_document_group}"
          .col-lg-8
            - global_timestamps = table.target_collection.data_types.map{ |key, value| key if value == "TimeStamp" && table.doc_group_columns.keys.include?(key) }.compact rescue []
            = f.select(:global_timestamp, global_timestamps, :selected => table.global_timestamp, :include_blank => true, :class => "input-highlight")
          .col-lg-4
            = f.submit "Save", :class => "btn btn-primary form-control"
```

No matter the length of the array I'm iterating over, the first iteration doesn't seem to work. All other iterations create the form as intended. If i had 3 objects in my array, my html looks like this

```
%h4
<div class="row puffer">
<form></form>
<form></form>
```

So it is successfully creating all the forms except for the first one. Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need `build: @build`, that's the point of scoping it through `@build.tables`.

Comment: you're right thanks! haha overlooked

Comment: I realize this isn't your question. However... Having a query like that (`@build.tables.where(build: @build, style: "raw")`) in your view is, IMO, smelly. I suggest you set a `@tables` variable in your controller and then do `@tables.each do |table|`.

Comment: you're probably right. The only reason why I initially chose to go this route is because I have other code that require going through the @build variable such as `@build.users` and `@build.targets`. I figured instead of passing all of those variables (`@users`, `@targets`) this way is not as clunky? However, your comment is definitely the correct and railsy way

Comment: I'm having the same problem, regardless of the collection I'm looping over. (Rails 4.2.8, Ruby 2.4.6)
```
- User.limit(5).each do |group|
      = form_for group do |f|
        = f.text_field :last_name
```

Comment: (I'm also apparently having trouble formatting code here.)

Answer (score 0):

Change the first part of your code to

```
= form_for table...
```

As a variable and not a `:symbol`.

Also per my comment, you don't need `build: @build`, that's the point of scoping it through `@build.tables`

```
- @build.tables.where(style: "raw").each do |table|
  = form_for table, :url => table_global_timestamp_path(table), :method => :post, :html => { :class => ""}, authenticity_token: true, remote: true do |f|
```

Comment: I changed table from symbol to variable and the problem still persists

Comment: whats the count of `@build.tables.where(style: "raw")`?

Comment: The count of @build.tables.where(style: "raw") is 3.